# "APN Settings are not available for this user" Help?

Tags: xiaomi, apn

I bought a Mi MIX 2 and it is not connecting on mobile data. WiFi everything else works perfect. But in the APN settings menu it reads that "APN Settings are not available..." I am using Verizon BTW. MIUI 8.5.7.0 How would I fix this?

Comment: Try creating one. Menu > New APN ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Verizon locks the APN settings. So if a reboot of the phone doesn't help, i would say the only option is to call Verizon